# delay() function does not work with addClass() function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I use delay() function before addClass() function then the class circle1 does not delay for some time.

My code is given below......

CSS:

```
.but{display:block; width:40px; height:40px; background-color:#F00; position:absolute;}

.circle1{display:block; width:145px; height:145px; position:absolute; left:10px; bottom:0px; border-radius:50%; border:5px solid rgba(100%,0%,20%,0.7); background-image:url(New%20folder/1st.jpg); background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; transform:scale(0);}
.zoom{transform:scale(1); transition:All 0.4s ease;}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".but").click(function() {
         $('.but').fadeOut(300);
         $('.circle1').delay(1000);
         $('.circle1').addClass("zoom");
    });
});
```

Comment: provide html code or create a fiddle pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), as `.delay()` is designed to work with queue as `addClass()` don't use queue.

```
$(".but").click(function() {
     $('.but').fadeOut(300);
     setTimeout(function(){
         $('.circle1').addClass("zoom");
     }, 1000);        
});
```

or, You can use [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

```
$(".but").click(function() {
     $('.but').fadeOut(300);    

     $('.circle1').delay(100)
               .queue(function() {
                   $(this).addClass("zoom");
                   $(this).dequeue();
               });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** `setTimeout()`

```
$(".but").click(function() {
         $('.but').fadeOut(300);
         setTimeout(function(){$('.circle1').addClass("zoom")},1000);
    });
```

**Method 2** `.queue`

```
$(".but").click(function() {
    $('.but').fadeOut(300);
    $('.circle1').delay(1000).queue(function () {
        $('.circle1').addClass("zoom");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.delay()` only works with jQuery methods that use the animation queue on the same DOM object.  So, since `.addClass()` doesn't use the animation queue, it doesn't cooperate with `.delay()`.

You can either trigger `addClass()` via a queued function or you can just use `setTimeout()`.

The simplest way is probably this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".but").click(function() {
         $('.but').fadeOut(300);
         setTimeout(function() {
             $('.circle1').addClass("zoom");
         }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay) methods works with the help of a queue system, so it will delay the execution of the next method in the next queue(the default queue is the `fx` queue). The `addClass` method does not make use of a queue for execution that is why it is not working.

You can add a function which adds the class to the target element to the queue using the [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue) method like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".but").click(function() {
    $('.but').fadeOut(300);
    $('.circle1').delay(1000).queue(function() {
      $('.circle1').addClass("zoom");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.zoom {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="but">but</button>
<div class="circle1">div</div>
```